# Cryptic error when trying to run POW

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack, rack-pow

I am having a rather weird error message when running POW for my rails app.

I followed the instructions:

```
- cd ~/.pow
- ln -s /Users/mingyeow/Dailymuses-Server-Side
```

And got this:

```
Error starting application
Your Rack app raised an exception when Pow tried to run it.
Error: '/Users/mingyeow/Dailymuses-Server-Side/.powrc' failed to load:
true &&
source '/Users/mingyeow/Dailymuses-Server-Side/.powrc' > /dev/null &&
env > '/var/folders/cl/fd2wt82149x9trkxmsvqrt500000gn/T/pow.18625.1358760244196.27206'
Error: '/Users/mingyeow/Dailymuses-Server-Side/.powrc' failed to load:
true &&
source '/Users/mingyeow/Dailymuses-Server-Side/.powrc' > /dev/null &&
env > '/var/folders/cl/fd2wt82149x9trkxmsvqrt500000gn/T/pow.18625.1358760244196.27206'
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:282:15)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:70:17)
    at maybeExit (child_process.js:362:16)
    at Process.onexit (child_process.js:398:5)
```

Tried resetting everything I could find.

Comment: Does a .powrc file exist in `Dailymuses-Server-Side`? If so, does it look like [this example](https://gist.github.com/4586541)?

Answer (score 1):

I've had the exact same error today with an Octopress install.

Does your .powrc look like the following?

```
if [ -f "$rvm_path/scripts/rvm" ] && [ -f ".rvmrc" ] ; then
   source "$rvm_path/scripts/rvm"
   source ".rvmrc"
fi
```

That's the one provided with Octopress, but I guess it's pretty generic.

In my case, I had modified the `.rvmrc` file and it contained a syntax error. I corrected the error, deleted the symlink in `~/.pow` and created it again, and all went back to normal.

Hope that helps!
(if not, maybe you should update your question with the content of your `.powrc` file)