# Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch: Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, rack-pow, gem-bundler

I am using a Mac with Pow, Ruby, Rails and a bunch of useful gems. I recently got this error whenever I try to open my app.

**Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch: Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0**

I understand the error, but I can't find why it is not using the proper version here.

Some information that can be useful:

### Stack Trace

```
Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch: Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:361:in `validate_ruby!'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:116:in `setup'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
~/Dropbox/Documents/project/Sites/project-profile/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/builder.rb:4:in `instance_eval'
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/builder.rb:4:in `initialize'
~/Dropbox/Documents/project/Sites/project-profile/config.ru:1:in `new'
~/Dropbox/Documents/project/Sites/project-profile/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:50:in `eval'
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:50:in `load_config'
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:43:in `initialize'
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:13:in `new'
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:13:in `run'
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/bin/nack_worker:4:in `<main>'
```

### RVM & Ruby version

```
$> ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin12.5.0]
$> rvm use 
Using /Users/Alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247
```

Any idea what I am missing here?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any .ruby-version files in your project, and you might need to paste your Gemfile too, if you have .ruby-version it is probably changing the version of ruby as you switch into the folder

Comment: Are you using both rbenv and rvm at the same time?

Comment: I am using RVM but I also have rbenv installed on my system, printing `rbenv versions` result was a bit confusing, sorry about that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I finally found out the solution in [RVM documentation](http://rvm.io/integration/pow):

> Pow has removed automated detection of rvm, here is how it can be
>   restored by creating  .powenv in the root of the project, according to
>   Pow docs it should not be checked in to source control (unless all
>   team members agree on that).

These lines must be added to the `.powenv` file at the root of your project. Then after restarting the server everything worked like a charm!

```
# detect `$rvm_path`
if [ -z "${rvm_path:-}" ] && [ -x "${HOME:-}/.rvm/bin/rvm" ]
then rvm_path="${HOME:-}/.rvm"
fi
if [ -z "${rvm_path:-}" ] && [ -x "/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm" ]
then rvm_path="/usr/local/rvm"
fi

# load environment of current project ruby
if
  [ -n "${rvm_path:-}" ] &&
  [ -x "${rvm_path:-}/bin/rvm" ] &&
  rvm_project_environment=`"${rvm_path:-}/bin/rvm" . do rvm env --path 2>/dev/null` &&
  [ -n "${rvm_project_environment:-}" ] &&
  [ -s "${rvm_project_environment:-}" ]
then
  echo "RVM loading: ${rvm_project_environment:-}"
  \. "${rvm_project_environment:-}"
else
  echo "RVM project not found at: $PWD"
fi
```

Comment: Where exactly is the .powenv file? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: You have to create it by yourself: `touch .powenv` at the root of the project directory. Then you can edit it with any text editor. Note that dot-files (filenames starting with a ".") are hidden by default on unix-like OS.

Comment: This fails with `.powrc' failed to load: true &&`

Comment: @Trip could it be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14435735/cryptic-error-when-trying-to-run-pow?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check version in `.rvmrc` in your project root folder. If you haven't got one create it. Move to your project folder in terminal and type in `rvm --create --rvmrc 2.0.0-p247@yourgemsetname`. After you have to direct to you parent folder and back to your project folder. Latest versions of `rvm` use `.ruby_version` instead of `.rvmrc`.

Answer (score 0):

`touch .ruby-version`

add `ruby-2.0.0`

Try again. Worked for me with Pow + RVM + ruby-2.2.1